# App-v second publishing server across VPN

Tags: xml, vpn, virtualization, appv

We've got two App-v servers on the go right now (APPV and APPDP), with the second in a separate location. APPDP is available through a VPN to our offices, though it will be available locally to those in the satellite office.

At present, client and publishing interaction works as intended with APPV (located here), but the APPDP gives an error "Publishing metadata not ready". Our management server sits on port 80 and publishing on 81, with APPV serving as both the management and publishing server. The firewall has been configured to allow traffic on the management port between the servers.

```
<PublishingServiceError>
<Message>Publishing metadata not ready</Message>
<Message>DownloadMetadataError (URL:http://APPV:81/Publishing/Metadata/)</Message>
<Message>Unable to connect to the remote server</Message>
```

It's also worth noting that both XML files (Publishingmetadata.xml and Raw_publishingmetadata.xml) are missing from ProgramData\Microsoft\AppV\Server\Publishing on APPDP.

Is it possible to have two publishing servers in separate locations? We want to avoid heavy link load between the sites. I don't have a huge amount of experience with App-v so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue has been resolved, our second publishing server has made a publishing attempt as of this morning. I'll detail what I did for anyone who runs across a similar issue.

After a lot of research, I came across some info regarding the default scripts located on your SQL database (program files\microsoft app v...\scripts\management) that are outdated. Microsoft seemingly left this mistake in between versions 5 and 5.1, so it's still relevant. Make the changes below:

```
In InsertVersionInfo.sql, locate the following line:

INSERT INTO dbo.SchemaChanges VALUES(@dbversion, @minserviceversion)

Change this to the following line:

INSERT INTO dbo.SchemaVersion VALUES(2)
```

and

```
In Permissions.sql, locate the following line:

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.SchemaChanges TO PUBLIC

Change this to the following line:

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.SchemaVersion TO PUBLIC
```

This should fix the problem, if your issue is the same as mine. I would suggest doing this anyway, as the xml schema govern the publishing metadata. Further information can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3031340.